# How to avoid bad practice of persisting resource integers (R.drawable.resource)

Tags: android, persistence, android-resources

Having a class which references to a resource value for a String and a drawable, I need to persist that class and load it in the future. I persist it with GSON and shared preferences.

The problem is that always I make a change on a resource of my application, the resourceID of the persisted values is not valid any more, because the resource IDs of all the resources in the application changes.

How can I avoid this problem? I need to persist that class..

This is a minimum sample of the code of the class I'm persisting:

```
public class SpaceshipUpdate {
    private int nameResource;
    private int imageResource;

    public SpaceshipUpdate(int nameResource, int imageResource){
        this.nameResource = nameResource;
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }
}
```

And how I create a new instance of that class:

```
SpaceshipUpdate u1 = new SpaceshipUpdate(R.string.laser1_title, R.drawable.shop_proton_laser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can persist the name of the resources(for example: "laser1_title") as string instead of `R.string.laser1_title` version and use this helper function (or something similar) to get that resource dynamically.

It might not be as fast, but if you don't have a lot of resources, you shouldn't notice any performance issues.

```
public static int has_resource_id(Context context,String name,String resource_type)
{
    final int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, resource_type,
            context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    return resourceId;
}
```

Comment: The problem of this solution is that you need to hardcode the name of the resource, or use a similar function to get the name of the resource for referencing it. So it's really slow for setting and for retrieving the resource, and for a game it's very bad to use slow solutions

Comment: @NullPointerException If you really want to "persist" something, you must have a "key" that doesn't change. so, why "hardcode the name of the resource" is a problem, it am not quite sure. As per the performance issue, I agree. But I have used this approach in a custom calendar app, where I had to show a 30 days, each day was a custom view, with a lot of features. I got the resources using this way. I didn't notice that much lag there, after a relatively slow start compared to few apps.

Comment: I posted my solution, please, can you take a look at it and give me your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I opted for this solution, instead of storing the resource ID's I created methods in the base classes that returns the value depending of the type of descendant class:

```
public int getName() {
    switch (type){
        case SPACESHIP_TYPE_1:
            return R.string.spaceship1;
        case SPACESHIP_TYPE_2:
            return R.string.spaceship2;
        case SPACESHIP_TYPE_3:
            return R.string.spaceship3;
        case SPACESHIP_TYPE_4:
            return R.string.spaceship4;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Doing this is not necessary to store the resource id's

Comment: Yes, this is a valid workaround. But consider the case, in a game, where you have 10 spaceship types, 50 person types, 100s of objects. When you access resources in this manner, **1.** if checks against every `case` inside `switch` until matched. if there are a LOT of variations, it can be even slower than my suggestion. **2.** when you have a LOT of variations, this is error prone, you have to write a LOT of cases which are almost similar. Ex.: for 89th object, `return R.string.object_no_89` before similar 88 lines, which is a LOT harder to debug and contains a LOT of *almost duplicate* code

Comment: yes, it's true, can be faster but also can be slower, only works for situations with los variations